# How can I match these function calls, and extract the nmae of the function and the first argument?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse an array of elements. Those who match a pattern like the following:
`Jim("jjanson", Customer.SALES);`

I want to create a hash table like `Jim => "jjanson"`
How can I do this?

I can not match the lines using:
`if($line =~ /\s*[A-Za-z]*"(.*),Customer.*\s*/)`

Answer (score 2):

You're not matching either the `'('` after the name, nor the `' '` after the comma, before "Customer.".

I can get `'jjanson"'` using this expression:

```
 /\s*[A-Za-z]\(*"(.*), Customer.*\s*/
```

But I assume you don't want `jjanson`***`"`***, so we need to modify it like so. (I tend to include the negative character class when I'm looking for simply-delimited stuff. So, in this case I'll make the expression `"[^"]*"`

```
 /\s*[A-Za-z]\(*"([^"]+)", Customer.*\s*/
```

Also, I try not to depend upon whitespace, presence or number, I'm going to replace the space with `\s*`. That you didn't notice that you skipped the whitespace is a good illustration of the need to say "ignore a bunch of whitespace".

```
 /\s*[A-Za-z]\(*"([^"]+)",\s*Customer.*\s*/
```

Now it's only looking for the sequence `','` + `'Customer'` in the *significant* characters. Functionally, the same, if more flexible.

But since you only do one *capture*, I can't see what you'd map to what. So I'll do my own mapping:

```
my %records;
while ( my $line = $source->()) { # simply feed for a source of lines.
    my ( $first, $user, $tag ) 
        = $line = m/\s*(\p{Alpha}+)\s*\(\s*"([^"]+)",\s*Customer\.(\S+?)\)\/
        ;
    $records{ $user } 
        = { first    => $first
          , username => $user
          , tag      => $tag 
          };
}
```

This is much more than you would tend to need in a one-off, quick solution. But I like to store as much of my input as seems significant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Jim("jjanson", Customer.SALES);` matches the syntax of a function call with two arguments. You can thus abuse [string `eval`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS;

my $info = extract_first_arg(q{ Jim("jjanson", Customer.SALES);} );
print Dump $info;

sub extract_first_arg {
    my $call = shift;
    my ($name) = ($call =~ m{ \A \s* (\w+) }x);
    unless ($name) {
        warn "Failed to find function name in '$call'";
        return;
    }
    my $username = eval sprintf(q{
        package My::DangerZone;
        no strict;
        local *{ %s } = sub { $_[0] };
        %s
    }, $name, $call);
    return { $name => $username };
}
```

Output:

```
---
Jim: jjanson
```

Or, you can abuse [autoloading](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsub#Autoloading):

```
our $AUTOLOAD;

print Dump eval 'no strict;' . q{ Jim("jjanson", Customer.SALES); };

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my ($fn) = ($AUTOLOAD =~ /::(\w+)\z/);
    return { $fn => $_[0] };
}
```

I would not necessarily recommend using these methods, especially on input that is not in your control, and in a situation where this script has access to sensitive facilities.

On the other hand, I have, in the right circumstances, utilized this kind of thing in transforming one given set of information into something that can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry I don't understand what you are proposing

Comment: You are trying to extract the name of a function, and the value of its first argument. So, I make up a function to return its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$line = 'Jim("jjanson", Customer.SALES)';
my %hashStore = (); #Jim("jjanson"
if($line=~m/^\s*([^\(\)]*)\(\"([^\"]*)\"/g) {  $hashStore{$1} = $2;  }
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hashStore;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Jim' => 'jjanson'
    };
```